# Failed to commit to a server, issue with mbstring php

Tags: php, mbstring

For some reason my application won't build on my server when I make a commit.
There have been no impactful updates on the server, anyone has an idea what this could be? The mbstring.so file is in the heroku folder.

Before the weekend there was no issue committing to the server, every build just fails.

```
remote: -----> Cleaning up...        
remote: -----> Building container_test from herokuish...        
remote: -----> Adding BUILD_ENV to build environment...        
remote:        -----> Warning: Multiple default buildpacks reported the ability to handle this app. The first buildpack in the list below will be used.        
remote:               Detected buildpacks: multi ruby nodejs php        
remote:        -----> Multipack app detected        
remote: =====> Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php        
remote: =====> Detected Framework: PHP        
remote: -----> Bootstrapping...        
remote: -----> Installing platform packages...        
remote:        - php (7.4.3)        
remote:        - ext-gd (bundled with php)        
remote:        - ext-mbstring (bundled with php)        
remote:        - ext-pcntl (bundled with php)        
remote:        - apache (2.4.41)        
remote:        - nginx (1.16.1)        
remote: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mbstring.so' (tried: /app/.heroku/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/mbstring.so (libonig.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /app/.heroku/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/mbstring.so.so (/app/.heroku/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/mbstring.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0        
remote: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mbstring.so' (tried: /app/.heroku/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/mbstring.so (libonig.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /app/.heroku/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/mbstring.so.so (/app/.heroku/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/mbstring.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0        
remote: -----> Installing dependencies...        
remote:        Composer version 1.9.1 2019-11-01 17:20:17        
remote:        PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mbstring.so' (tried: /app/.heroku/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/mbstring.so (libonig.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /app/.heroku/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/mbstring.so.so (/app/.heroku/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/mbstring.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0        
remote:        Loading composer repositories with package information        
remote:        Installing dependencies from lock file        
remote:        Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.        
remote:                
remote:          Problem 1        
remote:            - Installation request for erusev/parsedown 1.7.3 -> satisfiable by erusev/parsedown[1.7.3].        
remote:            - erusev/parsedown 1.7.3 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
remote:          Problem 2        
remote:            - Installation request for laravel/framework v5.7.28 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.7.28].        
remote:            - laravel/framework v5.7.28 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.        
remote:          Problem 3        
remote:            - Installation request for lcobucci/jwt 3.3.1 -> satisfiable by lcobucci/jwt[3.3.1].        
remote:            - lcobucci/jwt 3.3.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.        
remote:          Problem 4        
remote:            - Installation request for phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.9.0 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.9.0].        
remote:            - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.9.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.        
remote:          Problem 5        
remote:            - laravel/framework v5.7.28 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.        
remote:            - rairlie/laravel-locking-session v1.1.2 requires illuminate/session ~5.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.7.28].        
remote:            - Installation request for rairlie/laravel-locking-session v1.1.2 -> satisfiable by rairlie/laravel-locking-session[v1.1.2].        
remote:                
remote:          To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:        
remote:            - /app/.heroku/php/etc/php/php.ini        
remote:            - /app/.heroku/php/etc/php/conf.d/000-heroku.ini        
remote:            - /app/.heroku/php/etc/php/conf.d/010-ext-zend_opcache.ini        
remote:            - /app/.heroku/php/etc/php/conf.d/100-ext-gd.ini        
remote:            - /app/.heroku/php/etc/php/conf.d/110-ext-mbstring.ini        
remote:            - /app/.heroku/php/etc/php/conf.d/120-ext-pcntl.ini        
remote:            - /tmp/buildpackznVVG/conf/php/apm-nostart-overrides/apm-nostart-overrides.ini        
remote:          You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.        
remote:         
remote:  !     ERROR: Dependency installation failed!        
remote:  !             
remote:  !     The 'composer install' process failed with an error. The cause        
remote:  !     may be the download or installation of packages, or a pre- or        
remote:  !     post-install hook (e.g. a 'post-install-cmd' item in 'scripts')        
remote:  !     in your 'composer.json'.        
remote:  !             
remote:  !     Typical error cases are out-of-date or missing parts of code,        
remote:  !     timeouts when making external connections, or memory limits.        
remote:  !             
remote:  !     Check the above error output closely to determine the cause of        
remote:  !     the problem, ensure the code you're pushing is functioning        
remote:  !     properly, and that all local changes are committed correctly.        
remote:  !             
remote:  !     For more information on builds for PHP on Heroku, refer to        
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support        
remote:
```

Comment: Apart from the git push triggering the build this problem seems entirely unrelated to git. Fix the build problem (possibly by fixing the environment on the server) and that should be it.

Answer (score 0):

Fix was in here.
Apparently it is an Heroku error, creating an Aptfile in the root directory as well as adding buildpack-apt and the buildpack-php#v171 resolved the issue.

https://github.com/gliderlabs/herokuish/issues/529